# SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 - Tempdb “Available free space” showing negative value

Tags: sql-server-2008, tempdb

Please help as this issue is driving me nuts...

Tempdb has four data files & one log file. They are all located on the same dedicated drive.

When I right click on tempdb in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to view Properties --> General...I'm seeing "Size" as ~65000 MB with "Space Available" as ~64000 MB. However, when I try to shrink the files via the GUI, I see that the "currently allocated space" hasn't changed & is still showing the initial size.

This is also where the "Available free space" is shown as a negative number. The only work around I have found so far is to restart SQL Server to flush out tempdb, but I can't keep on doing this.

Has anyone ever come across this & know the root cause/permanent solution for it please?

Thanks in advance!